# Distincted ids for grouped values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to count the distinct ids in each numb and store them in a column :
Tried this:

```
WITH T AS(
SELECT 
  MAX(CASE WHEN LOGS like'CAR%' then REPLACE(LOGS,'CAR-','')end)as CAR,
  MAX(CASE WHEN LOGS like 'MOT%' then REPLACE(LOGS,'MOT-','')end)as MOTO,
  MAX(CASE WHEN LOGS like 'BICYCLE%' then REPLACE(LOGS,'BICYCLE-','')end)as BICYCLE,
  MAX(CASE WHEN LOGS like 'SHIP%' then REPLACE(LOGS,'SHIP-','')end)as SHIP,
  ID,
  ORIG,
  DATE_ID ,
  NUMB,
  STEPS 
from dbo.test
group by ORIG,DATE_ID,ID ,NUMB,STEPS
)
SELECT ID,ORIG,NUMB,STEPS,DATE_ID,CAR,MOTO,BICYCLE,SHIP,
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM dbo.test tp WHERE ORIG= '4567') as COUNTER
from t
where ORIG= '4567'
  and NUMB in('1515','1921','2121')
GROUP BY ID,ORIGIN_URI,NUMB,STEPS,DATE_ID,CAR,MOTO,BICYCLE,SHIP
```

Receive this  output:

```
+----+--------------+--------+-------+----------+-------+------+---------+------+---------+
| ID |     ORIG     | NUMB | STEPS | DATE_ID  |  CAR  | MOTO | BICYCLE | SHIP | COUNTER |
+----+--------------+--------+-------+----------+-------+------+---------+------+---------+
|  1 |   4567       |   1515 |     1 | 20201010 | HONDA | NULL | NULL    | NULL |       3 |
|  1 |   4567       |   1515 |     2 | 20201010 | HONDA | NULL | NULL    | NULL |       3 |
|  1 |   4567       |   1515 |     3 | 20201010 | HONDA | NULL | NULL    | NULL |       3 |
|  2 |   4567       |   1921 |     1 | 20201111 | NULL  | KTM  | NULL    | NULL |       3 |
|  3 |   4567       |   2121 |     1 | 20201231 | NULL  | NULL | NULL    | BOAT |       3 |
|  3 |   4567       |   2121 |     2 | 20201231 | NULL  | NULL | NULL    | BOAT |       3 |
|  3 |   4567       |   2121 |     3 | 20201231 | NULL  | NULL | NULL    | BOAT |       3 |
|  3 |   4567       |   2121 |     4 | 20201231 | NULL  | NULL | NULL    | BOAT |       3 |
+----+--------------+--------+-------+----------+-------+------+---------+------+---------+
```

As you can see `COUNTER` columns has the count of distincted ids but for all `NUMB`

I want to output this:

```
+----+--------------+--------+-------+----------+-------+------+---------+------+---------+
| ID |     ORIG     | NUMB | STEPS | DATE_ID  |  CAR  | MOTO | BICYCLE | SHIP | COUNTER |
+----+--------------+--------+-------+----------+-------+------+---------+------+---------+
|  1 |   4567       |   1515 |     1 | 20201010 | HONDA | NULL | NULL    | NULL |       2 |
|  1 |   4567       |   1515 |     2 | 20201010 | HONDA | NULL | NULL    | NULL |       2 |
|  2 |   4567       |   1515 |     1 | 20201010 | HONDA | NULL | NULL    | NULL |       2 |
|  2 |   4567       |   1921 |     1 | 20201111 | NULL  | KTM  | NULL    | NULL |       1 |
|  3 |   4567       |   2121 |     1 | 20201231 | NULL  | NULL | NULL    | BOAT |       2 |
|  3 |   4567       |   2121 |     2 | 20201231 | NULL  | NULL | NULL    | BOAT |       2 |
|  3 |   4567       |   2121 |     3 | 20201231 | NULL  | NULL | NULL    | BOAT |       2 |
|  1 |   4567       |   2121 |     1 | 20201231 | NULL  | NULL | NULL    | BOAT |       2 |
+----+--------------+--------+-------+----------+-------+------+---------+------+---------+
```

1. 1515 has 2 ids
2. 1921 has 1 id
3. 2121 has 2 ids

I tried also to place a `GROUP BY` NUMB inside `(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM dbo.test tp WHERE ORIG= '4567')` but didn't work.

Comment: Why do you have a `GROUP BY` in your outer query? It has no aggregation.

Comment: @Larnu I tried to use the count(distinct id) out of the select so I forgot the GROUP BY. Although the output do not fulfil the desired output again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you seem to want is:

```
count(distinct steps) over (partition by orig, numb)
```

Alas, SQL Server doesn't support `count(distinct)` with window functions.

Happily, there is an easy workaround (which begs the question as to why the above syntax is not supported):

```
(dense_rank() over (partition by orig, numb order by steps asc) +
 dense_rank() over (partition by orig, numb order by steps desc) - 1
) as counter
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon. It worked when I change the steps to id. Only one question why the result is +1 of the normal? I mean for 1515 it returned 3 instead of 2. I placed a -1 and its fine now, for all the results but I am curious of why this happens

Comment: @Thkas . . . It returns 1 more than the count because I left out the `- 1`.  `dense_rank()` starts at `1`, so the result is off by `1`.